# how would i go about emulating mouse devices correctly?

Tags: vbscript, mouse, wdk

I have a device simulation framework vbscript file I use to create emulated usb mouse devices but I have a problem: how can I pass x,y for a specific usb mouse device without ending the script before all mouse devices are done? I thought about it and could use a file with x,y values but that might slow down the speed at which responses are received or not be in real time in worried about. 
An example would be me sending 3,3 for x,y for device 0 during first loop then second loop i send 4,4 for x,y for device1. Im stumped as to how this can be done.

Anyone have any ideas?
Code for reference is here:
http://kinectmultipoint.codeplex.com
I just need to organize the code properly but I will try the file idea while wating on response

Comment: can't find the code there, please publish the relevant part of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have implementation of my mouse program with kinect now i figured out the answer to this. Please visit link above to download code and no its not a direct download link you need to select downloads from top navigation bar and go to correct download.

If you wish to help me improve the code i've started combined the kinect and vbscript file together and progress is good but need successful two person kinect test. 
I used command line paramters in vbscript to pass parameters with the mouse data.
Might in future research making an emulated multi-mouse driver because i dont like using the vbscript.